# Django order_by not working properly

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get all the conversations ordered by it last message, but when I use the `order_by` clausule, the conversations are repeated.

Query without order_by:

```
conversaciones = Conversacion.objects.filter(usuarios=request.user)
```

Result (Grouped by Conversations but not ordered by the most recent last message first):

[image: Grouped by Conversations but not ordered by the most recent last message first]

Query with order_by:

```
conversaciones = Conversacion.objects.filter(usuarios=request.user).order_by('-mensaje__fechaEnvio')
```

Result:

[image: WTF]

My models.py:

```
class Mensaje(models.Model):
    remitente = models.ForeignKey('Usuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='remitente')
    destinatario = models.ForeignKey('Usuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='destinatario')
    cuerpo = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(750)]) 
    leido = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fechaEnvio = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    conversacion = models.ForeignKey('Conversacion', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-fechaEnvio'] 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.remitente) + ' -> ' + str(self.destinatario)


class Conversacion(models.Model):
    usuarios = models.ManyToManyField('Usuario', related_name='usuarios')
    agresion = models.ForeignKey('Agresion', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def ultimoMensaje(self):
        return self.mensaje_set.latest('fechaEnvio')
```

Comment: Becuase there are many Mensaje's per Conversacion and you ask it to order by it. use `.distinct()` to get only one of each.

Comment: you can also use distinct to specify which field you want to be unique. However, this only works with postgres, and is not available with mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
conversaciones = Conversacion.objects.filter(usuarios=request.user).annotate(max_fecha=Max('mensaje__fechaEnvio')).order_by('-max_fecha')
```

I'm using MySQL so I can't use distinct with params.

Answer (score 1):

As @jota suggested, I can add something in your model Mesanje. Make ordering a tuple and don't forget to add a comma and don't forget to make migrations again.

```
class Mesanje(models.Model):
      ........
      class Meta:
           ordering = ('-fechaEnvio',)
```